# Erro ao compilar código com import java.util.Random; random.nextInt()

Tags: java, compilação, random

Estou estudando a linguagem de programação java e encontrei um obstaculo, por algum acaso não consigo compilar este codigo

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Random {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Random num = new Random();
        System.out.println(num.nextInt());
    }
}
```

[image: ArchLinux]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O real problema você deve observar na primeira linha de erro:

> Random is already defined in this compilation unit

Você deu o nome de Random para a sua classe, e o compilador está confundindo com o `java.util.Random`. Como você não tem o método `nextInt()` definido na sua classe ele diz que esse método não existe.

Troque o nome da sua classe para evitar conflitos que é para funcionar Ok.

Veja um exemplo funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/ZACEcP).

Comment: Muito obrigado! era exatamente isso daqui 5 minutos eu qualifico a resposta (y)

Answer (score 2):

Tente da Seguinte forma:

```
public class Random {
    public static void main(String[] args){
       java.util.Random num = new java.util.Random();
        System.out.println(num.nextInt());
    }
}
```

Desta forma não é necessário o `import`.

Na verdade se importa, ele deve acusar erro !

Isto ocorre porque o nome da sua classe também é `Random`.

Comment: ..Bom também :)

Comment: Verdade bom também.